# Как исправить следующую ошибку MongoDB?

Tags: yii2, mongodb

При подключении к базе на mongoDB выдаете следующую ошибку

> no such cmd: listCollections in

не подскажите почему она впадает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вызвать метод  listCollections на базе данных
Привожу пример

JS (shell):

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

node.js:

```
db.listCollections()
```

non-JS (shell only):

```
show collections
```